# Add class when press on a random area - jquery

Tags: jquery

I have 3 areas and 3 spans, I want when I click on a random area to add a class to the first span then when I click on another random area to add the same class to the second span and than for the last area when I click to add same class to the third span.

```
    <div id="check-box" class="block">
         <ul class="block">
             <li class="unchecked unchecked1"></li>
             <li class="unchecked unchecked2"></li>
             <li class="unchecked unchecked3"></li>
         </ul>
    </div>

    <map name="diff">
        <area  shape="poly" coords="76,269,50,243,51,221,82,255" href="#" class="diff diff1" onfocus="blur();">
        <area shape="poly" coords="152,347,253,292,264,307,167,358" href="#" class="diff         diff2" onfocus="blur();">
        <area shape="poly" coords="93,244,164,215,171,233,97,264" href="#" class="diff diff3" onfocus="blur();">
    </map>
```

This will be game called Find The Difference, so when you guess the first difference, the first span will get a class that will show like a checked button, than when you press on the second random difference the second span gets the class with the checked image.

I tryed this but it checkes all the spans when I find the first difference:

```
    $('.diff').mousedown(function(){
    $('#check-box li').append('<span class="checked block"></span>');
    });
```

Comment: Where is span? Which class you want to add? What have you tried? IMHO A perfect question for close vote

Comment: You mean `li` not `span`

Comment: I edited now, I was appending a span to the li.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.diff').on('click', function(e){
    $( "#check-box li" ).not( ".checked_li" ).first().addClass( "checked_li" ).append('<span class="checked block"></span>');
})
```

Comment: The script will select the first li that has no checked_li class, adds checked_li class then appends the span tag to it.